Is my "escaping" wrong - or is it something else?
Here's what I'm trying to do (in a script):
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ ! $("/usr/bin/scp seamus@fumier.local:/Users/seamus/Downloads/imgutils/image-utils* /home/pi/testscp") ]]; then
    printf "\nERROR & EXIT: 'scp' failed \n"
    exit 1
fi
printf "success!\n"

I've tried doing this in a few ways, but nothing seems to work. Here's what I get from the above:
./testscp.sh: line 3: /usr/bin/scp seamus@fumier.local:/Users/seamus/Downloads/imgutils/image-utils* /home/pi/testscp: No such file or directory

ERROR & EXIT: 'scp' failed

The scp command runs OK when it's on a line by itself. If I do that, I can test for $0 - which works OK... but I'd prefer to do it all in a single line. What am I missing?

Use if on its own, and quote the argument containing the glob intended for scp:
if ! /usr/bin/scp 'seamus@fumier.local:/Users/seamus/Downloads/imgutils/image-utils*' /home/pi/testscp; then
    printf>&2 "\nERROR & EXIT: 'scp' failed \n"
    exit 1
fi
printf "success!\n"


Thanks to you both (incl Stéphane).  I don't think I'd have ever thought of eliminating test!  Can you provide a reference for that?

A reference saying not to use [[? I’m not aware of anything like that. Would the definition of if in the Bash manual be useful? See also the POSIX spec for if.

The definition of if incl this: if test-commands; then .... And [[ is a test command (right?). Perhaps I'm trying to clear my confusion with the wrong questions, but I'm still confused.  :-/

test-commands there is used to specify the role of the commands, as opposed to consequent-commands. There’s no connection to the test command itself (or variants such as [ and [[); any command (or list of commands) can be used here.

I think I've learned something, but the "learning" is more like stubbing my toe than acquiring new knowledge  :)

I understand the feeling! If you’re used to if [ … ]; then or if [[ … ]]; then it can feel like that’s just how if is used (and that matches how it’s used in other programming languages). But with the shell, it can be decomposed — [ is itself a command, and any command can be used with if. Basically, whenever you want to check $?, instead of doing command; if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then …, if command; then works just as well.

@Seamus Essentially, any command can be a test-command, as long as it returns 0 on success and 1 on failure. Works for test / [, true, false, mkdir, scp, etc.

@marcelm: "any command can be a test-command,"...  If that were true, why would we need a test command in the first place?

The test command implements specific types of tests. Just because any command can be a test-command doesn’t mean that all of a sudden every type of test is implemented — any command can be a test-command, but you need commands implementing the tests you want.

@Seamus The Bash manual (so typical of Bash!) uses a misleading wording: test-commands. The POSIX Shell Command Language specification is more clear, using the term compound-list.

@Seamus It is true. test exists because it can check things like "are these two strings equal?" or "does this file exist and is it writable for me?", which mkdir and scp can't do for you. test can check for a whole barrage of useful things, which is why it's frequently used together with if. But again, you can use any command, and there's many scenarios (such as yours) where another command is more appropriate than test.

OK... I think I've got it - finally  :)

In bash, quotes are used to delimit a SINGLE label which would otherwise be interpreted as multiple labels (due to whitespace characters). So when bash reads:
if [[ ! $("/usr/bin/scp seamus@fumier.local:/Users/seamus/Downloads/imgutils/image-utils* /home/pi/testscp") ]]

It interprets this as:
if [[ ! $( LONG_EXECUTABLE_NAME_WITH_FUNNY_CHARACTERS ) ]]; then

Your quotes are in the wrong place.
In order to decompose that into an executable, there are multiple ways this could be written, but simply:
if [[ ! $(/usr/bin/scp seamus@fumier.local:/Users/seamus/Downloads/imgutils/image-utils* /home/pi/testscp) ]]; then

would suffice.
But as @StephenKitt says, the combination of test ([[...]]) and expansion ($(...)) is redundant. Indeed (as ikkachu points out below) this is testing for a non-null response on stdout, NOT the exit code of scp.

but I'd prefer to do it all in a single line.

That's a question of style rather than functionality, but I suggest it is not good style to write scripts with very long lines.

it's just that if [[ ! $(/usr/bin/scp ...) ]]; would test if scp's output is empty, which likely isn't the best way to test if it worked.

Good point! I was too focussed on the escaping issue.
